# TFS 2015 - persistent decrease of disk space

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are experiencing an ever decreasing disk space on our TFS 2015 server.

I like to know how to identify which Project(s) in a TFS 2015 collection takes up the most disk space and to identify the table(s) in the TFS database.

Would this be in the tbl_Contents that store this information?

Also, I noticed we don't have tbl_File, was this removed from TFS 2015?

Please kindly advise on any solution.

Comment: One of the things you should check is your log files for the collection databases on your server. You should be able to find their location when viewing the properties of a database in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below to find the Team Project Collection databases and their sizes, in descending size order, to check which collection database has big size:

```
use master
select DB_NAME(database_id) AS DBName, (size/128) SizeInMB
 FROM sys.master_files 
 where type=0  and substring(db_name(database_id),1,4)='Tfs_' and DB_NAME(database_id)<>'Tfs_Configuration' order by size desc
```

Then you can find out which tables are large with query:

```
USE Tfs_CollectionName
CREATE TABLE #t 
( [name] NVARCHAR(128), [rows] CHAR(11), reserved VARCHAR(18), 
data VARCHAR(18), index_size VARCHAR(18), unused VARCHAR(18))
GO
INSERT #t
EXEC [sys].[sp_MSforeachtable] 'EXEC sp_spaceused "?"'
GO
SELECT
name as TableName,
Rows,
ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(reserved, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as ReservedMB,
ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(data, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as DataMB,
ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(index_size, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as IndexMB,
ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(unused, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as UnusedMB
FROM #t
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(reserved, ' KB','') as float) DESC
GO
Drop table #t
```

In TFS 2015, instead of tbl_File, there are tbl_FileMetadata and tbl_FileReference in database.

> If you want to clean up your databse, it's not recommended to handle
>   in database directly. Please follow tutorial [Cleaning up old data](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/clean-up-data)
>   to clean Team Projects, Files, TFS VC Content, Test Attachments and
>   XAML Builds.
>
> Also, it should be noted that the size of the SQL data files will not
>   decrease after you perform any of the below commands, since SQL will
>   reserve the space for later use.

Comment: Thanks for the queries. Is there a way of finding out individual users or sub-projects that are taking up the most space?

Comment: Table Name Rows Reserved MB Data MB Index MB Unused MB
tbl_Content 1827438     57056.77 56957.1 30.68 68.98
tbl_LocalVersion 31232696    17416.55 16368.19 994.09 54.27
tbl_Version 5389133     5617.6 1905.95 3709.47 2.18
tbl_Command 5147388     1661.3 1652 8.02 1.29
tbl_WorkItemCoreWere 912607      1433.67 221.61 1206.46 5.6

Comment: Our tbl_Contents table is ever increasing. Is there a query to determine which project (within the tbl_Contents table) are taking up most of the space?